# How to extend customer registration with attributes specially radio button

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I want to extend the customer Registration form of the frontend with some custom customer attributes. I tried a TextBox and a RadioButton. The TextBox works perfektly. 
But the RadioButton value won't stored.

What is wrong?

I added a sql scipt

```
...
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'test2', array(
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'label'             => 'Test2',
    'global'            => 1,
    'visible'           => 1,
    'required'          => 0,
    'default'           => 0,
    'sort_order'        => 130
));

$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'test2');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
//$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();


$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'test', array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'label'             => 'Test',
    'global'            => 1,
    'visible'           => 1,
    'required'          => 0,
    'default'           => 0,
));

$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'test');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
//$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
...
```

I extend my config

```
<global>
    ...
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
            <test>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
            </test>
            <test2>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
            </test2>
         </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
    ...
</global>
```

I extend a copy of register.phtml

```
        <!--Text Test-->
        <li>
            <label for="test" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="test" id="test_1" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTest()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Test')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
            </div>
        </li>

        <!--Radio Button Test-->
        <li class="field">
            <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Do you want to ...?');?></label>

            <div class="field">

                <!--Yes-->
                <input type="radio" id="yes_test2" name="test2" value="0" <?php if($this->getFormData()->getTest2()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="validate-one-required-by-name" />
                <label for="yes_test2">
                    <span title="<?php echo $this->__('Yes');?>"><?php echo $this->__('Yes');?></span>
                </label>

                <!--No-->
                <input type="radio" id="no_test2" name="test2" value="1" checked="checked" class="validate-one-required-by-name" />
                <label for="no_test2">
                    <span title="<?php echo $this->__('No');?>"><?php echo $this->__('No');?></span>
                </label>

            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Have you tried someting?

Comment: I tried some hints, but it doesn't work. I added the attribute to the customer_account_create form of the used_in_forms data. Also I added the field to the fieldsets of my custom config. Additionally I named the attribute Id and name of my new input field (radio box). But nothing helped....

Answer (score 1):

if you search on Google for your question ("Magento custom attribute customer") you would get several results containing one or two modules that can do this for you and some posts from this site on how to do it yourself

Here is a link to above mentioned results: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=magento%20custom%20attributes%20customer

And a link to a module I've used in previous projects which can also be found amidst these google results: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-by-amasty.html

Comment: Thx for the info. I found some links before and I did create a the attribute in database. I copied the register template and added radio button for testing. But I don't know how the value will be stored in the registration process during the user is registering?

Comment: That's a bit broad to answer here. But basically the data sent from the registration page is handled by a controller and mapped to an object that commits it to the database

Comment: Ok so I have to extend the AccountController to update the  new field?